# How do I enable member login to a specific directory including sub-directories in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a web application where I want only member access. They should log in to access the directory and all its sub-directories and files.

Is there a plugin for this?

Example; My app folder is in the root wordPress installation directory.

```
http://localhost/wordpress-site/webapp
```

Under the webapp, I have the `index.php` to that launches the application.

I would like to redirect users to login before accessing the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file and use the function `is_user_logged_in`.

For example:
page-member.php

1º - Create a page called "member".

2º - Create a file page-member.php and upload to your theme directory.

3º - In the file, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
echo 'you are logged guy! see this content...';
// Here you can put your content
} else {
echo 'login to acess this page';
// Here you can put the login form
}
?>
```

Comment: My directory is outside the theme directory.

Comment: You can use include to this files and create the default pages. If you have a member area, you need to put the wordpress to work together.